# Accessing The Control Panel In Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, control-panel

I usually use *Search*, to access the Control Panel, by typing in the words Control Panel on the Start Screen, and the search result for Control Panel is displayed even before typing the full words.

[image]

Or I use the *Run command* accessed by pressing *Windows + R* on the keyboard:

[image]

What other ways exist for starting the Control Panel in Windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Neither of the things you listed are unique to Windows 8.1.  They both work as described in 7 (for example).

Comment: @techie007 I know (I didn't say they were). Those are the two ways I know how to launch the Control Panel.

Comment: @techie007 Fair Enough I did a search, but I didn't come across that.

Comment: Well the ones in the question I tagged as a duplicate should be plenty of other ways for you. :)

Comment: @techie007 Thats fine

Comment: How about just use the charm?  CTRL+I will provide you a quick way to reach the `Control Pannel`.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I saw that in the other answers posted on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Start button and there should be an option for Control Panel, as well as some more advanced things like Computer Management.